# How to use variable from a function which inside another function in another function

Tags: python

```
def func():
    a = 'abc'
    def func2():
        b = 'bcd'
        return b
    return a

def func3():
    c = func()()
    return c

print(func3())
```

How to use value from variable b from func2 in func3, above is what I have tried, got an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-30-cfaa7d1d3a78>", line 12, in <module>
    print(func3())

  File "<ipython-input-30-cfaa7d1d3a78>", line 9, in func3
    c = func()()

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: The problem is with the additional `()` in func3. It should be `c = func()`

Comment: `func2` is never used; did you mean `return func2` instead of `return a`?

Comment: try removing extra `()` in `c = func()()`, and check if that helps.

Comment: when I removed one () from func()(), i got the value of a from func(), instead of b from func2()

Comment: I need the return a for another purpose

Comment: I agree with others that it's not clear exactly what you're asking for, or why you want to do this. Both would help you get better responses.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

1. As pointed out by the commenters you need to remove the extra **`()`** you have after **`func()`**.
2. You never call **`func2()`** anywhere.

---

**SIDE NOTE**

It's confusing what you're trying to accomplish with this code... i.e. do you want both **`a`** and **`b`** available to **`func3()`**? Or just **`b`**.

---

If all you want is to return **`b`** so that **`c=b`** the code below will accomplish that.

```py
def func():
    a = 'abc'
    def func2():
        b = 'bcd'
        return b
    return func2()

def func3():
    c = func()
    return c

print(func3())
```

This will yield **`bcd`**.

---

If you want to return **`a` and `b`** so that **`c=('abc', 'bcd')`** the code below will accomplish that.

```py
def func():
    a = 'abc'
    def func2():
        b = 'bcd'
        return b
    return a, func2()

def func3():
    c = func()
    return c

print(func3())
```

This will yield **`abc`, `bcd`**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understood what are you asking but it seems like you never call the func2(). Try to add it in the return of func().

```
def func():
    a = 'abc'
    def func2():
        b = 'bcd'
        return b    
    return a + func2()

def func3():
    c = func()
    return c

print(func3())
```

Whith this solution my output is:

```
abcbcd
```